# Apache redirect query

Tags: linux, apache, tomcat, redirect

I'm stuck at the below scenario.

I've an application deployed in tomcat named "foo". I'm using mod_proxy at apache level to redirect the request from apache to tomcat. Below is the config for it.

```
ProxyPass        /foo  https://dev.apprlc.com:8080/foo
ProxyPassReverse /foo  https://dev.apprlc.com:8080/foo
```

I want to show maintenance page to the users when I'm doing some maintenance to the application. Below is the configuration.

```
RewriteCond /etc/apache/conf/MAINT -f
RewriteRule ^/foo$ /maintenance.html [R=302,L,NC]
```

This works just fine. But, I want to maintain a secret URI that I can use during the maintenance time. like `https://dev.webrlc.com/maint-test`.
For this I've made the following configuration.

```
RewriteCond /etc/apache/conf/MAINT -f
RewriteRule ^/foo$ /maintenance.html [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteCond /etc/apache/conf/MAINT -f
RewriteRule ^/maint-test$ /foo [PT]
```

This doesn't work & I can see it's pretty obvious. `/maint-test` will redirect to `/foo` and `/foo` inturn will redirect to `/maintenance.html` rather than fetching the `/foo` application from tomcat.

Could someone please help me on how to resolve it ? Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Add the P flag to use reverse proxy. Instead of pointing it to /foo, directly send the request to tomcat.

`RewriteCond /etc/apache/conf/MAINT -f 
RewriteRule ^/maint-test$ https://dev.apprlc.com:8080/foo [P]`

Comment: Did you use the exact configuration? The 2 flags [P] and [PT] are different. The response that I have given above, will send the request from Apache to Tomcat using mod_proxy. The configuration that you have used is sending the request from /maint-test (apache) to /foo (still on apache).